# How to find the number of steps between any number in spiral matrix and the center?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Can any one help or giving algorithm to find the number of steps from any number `n` to the center of a spiral matrix:

Spiral matrix could be of any odd size, like this one of size `5`

```
17    16    15    14    13
18     5     4     3    12
19     6     1     2    11
20     7     8     9    10
21    22    23    24    25
```

How to find number of steps from any number like from 13 to the center 1? In In this example, from 13 to 1, the number of steps (going only left and right down up) is **4**.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
% given
n = 13;            
A = spiral(5);

[ii,jj] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A == n)); % x,y index of n
[c] = ceil(size(A)/2);                   % index of center
dis = abs(c(1) - ii) + abs(c(2) - jj);   % distance
```

Comment: is there anotehr way without using prebuidl functions? using only loops and move in directions ?

Comment: @rebiccaangy maybe there is, but than its obviously homework, and we are not eager to help, if you do not at least show what you have tried and convince us, that you have tried.